# Find the residue of $\frac{1 - \cos z}{z^{3} (z-3)}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Is my solution correct? Also, are there removable singularities? Im having trouble classifying singularities

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes......you can also see that around $0$ the series expansion looks like 
$$ -1/6z -1/18 - z/216 \ - .... etc $$
So at zero you have a simple pole of order 1. This clearly follows as for $z \rightarrow 0 $ you have
$$  z(1-\cos(z))/z^3(z-3) =  2\sin^2(z/2)/z^2(z-3)\sim 1/2(z-3) \rightarrow -1/6$$
Hence $ z^k(1-\cos(z))/z^3(z-3) \sim z^{k-1}/2(z-3) \rightarrow 0 $ for all $ k \geq 2 $. Thus the Laurent series starts from $1/z $.